# ASP:NET MVC Route Config allow #

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routeconfig

I have a `RouteConfig.cs` file in my application, and when I go to the route `http://localhost:49735/applicationform/-5622850/G0085` it's all well and dandy, but when I try to go to the route `http://localhost:49735/applicationform/-5622850/#G0085` it can't find it, how can I allow `#` in my url route?

The RouteConfig.cs file looks like this:

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute(
           "applicationform",
           "applicationform/{id}/{itemnumber}",
           "~/Source/1UI/ApplicationForm.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser won't send anything after (and including) the #, so think again.